# How to import remote server module in Fabric?

Tags: python, django, fabric

I am using Fabric for code deployment on my server. As with the code deployment sometimes I also need to migrate database accordingly. I can hard code the apps for which I need to create migrations but the problem is I have 3 servers and on all these 3 servers I have different apps installed. So I was wondering if could just import the settings.py file from the desired server and then check if the apps are installed on that server or not. I tried to download the settings.py from the server and then import that but that is not working. It keeps giving me error `no module named assessment_engine`.
So is it really possible to import settings.py from remote server into my local fabric file.

Comment: You are using a single function call to deploy 3 different projects on different servers with different requirements? I don't really understand your workflow. Shouldn't your remote projects hold individual requirements files that can be called when executing pip remotely to make sure the correct packages are installed

Comment: no, I have different functions for deployment. Based on these functions only my environment variables are initialized. For example I have a function deploy which is used by all three functions deploy_dev, deploy_ith, deploy_prod. When I run command ``fab deploy_dev`` all the environment variables are initialized to work on development server and then deploy function is called. Everything is working fine. But I wish to carry out migrations. For that I need to check which applications are installed on that server. For that I need settings.py file. I am able to download it but cannot import.

Comment: why doesn't `run("/path/to/venv/bin/python /path/to/manage.py migrate")` work for you?